# How to detect when a member joins & leaves a voice channel

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am working on a discord bot that would need to detect when a user joins & leaves a channel. I have tried this on line 4 because if the user's connection doesn't change, it won't run.
But this does not work. Here is my entire section of code.

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
// check for bot
if (oldState.member.user.bot) return;
if (oldState.member.voice === newState.member.voice) return;//<- here
client.channels.cache.get('777782275004825640').send(`${oldState.member} joined`);
});
```

I've also tried ***.connection*** but it doesn't work with my current setup. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it!
After some testing, I found out that when a channel was updated one of four things would happen.

1. if the user joined the `oldState.channelID` returned null
2. if the user left the `newState.channelID` returned null
3. if the user muted themselves or were deafened the `oldState.channelID` was equal to `newState.channelID`
4. if the user moved channels  `oldState.channelID` did not equal `newState.channelID`

my `Discord.Client()` is set as `client`, so if yours is different change that

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
    if(oldState.channelID === newState.channelID) {
        console.log('a user has not moved!')
    }
    if(oldState.channelID != null && newState.channelID != null && newState.channelID != oldState.channelID) {
        console.log('a user switched channels')
    }
    if(oldState.channelID === null) {
        console.log('a user joined!')
    }
    if (newState.channelID === null) {
        console.log('a user left!')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet and please let me know how it worked for you.

```js
let oldChannel = oldState.voiceChannel;
let newChannel = newState.voiceChannel;

if(oldChannel === undefined && newChannel !== undefined) {
  // User has joined a channel
} else if(newChannel === undefined) {
  // User has left a channel
}
```

Comment: I have just tried it, however, the else if statement always fires on any update, including when I mute myself and deafen myself. and it doesn't fire when I leave